# Android NotificationCompat.Builder addPerson example

Tags: android, notifications, android-appcompat, contacts, android-9.0-pie

I am looking for an example of the NotificationCompat.Builder's method addPerson.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#addPerson(java.lang.String)) I can see that I can either provide the contact's [CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI) or that the system can also resolve **mailto:** or **tel:** schemes.

Given this, here is my test:

- I created an Android P emulator
- I added a contact to the contact provider (through the Contacts app) with an email address foo@bar.com

Then I used **mailto:** scheme with the following code :

```
private fun createNotification(contactEmail: String) {
        val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_chat_black_24px)
                .setContentTitle("Contact found")
                .setContentText("Contact $contactEmail")
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .addPerson("mailto:$contactEmail")

        val mNotificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build())

    }
```

The notification is well displayed but I cannot see the association with the contact or person. How is it supposed to look like and how can I know if it worked ? As I cannot notice anything (even a log) I suppose that it does not work.

Also, if you are not using the **mailto:** or **tel:** scheme, how are you supposed to retrieve the contact's [CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI) ?

Any pointer or code sample would help. Thanks !

Comment: what execlty you want to do, do you want to show person name and email send option?

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari for instance yes but I know I could use a notification action. I want to know what this feature is supposed to do. For instance would it allow me to display the contact's thumbnail as the notification icon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states: "Depending on user preferences, this annotation may allow the notification to pass through interruption filters, and to appear more prominently in the user interface."
So I guess to test this feature you should go into your emulator settings -> sound -> Do not disturb here you see the exceptions. 
When in do not disturb mode, if the email address you are passing belongs to someone in the "exceptions" the notification will be displayed otherwise it won't.